# React Native Linking to android application

Tags: android, react-native

Im trying to open [Get Taxi Drivers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gettaxi.dbx.android) and [WheelyPartner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wheely.groundio) applications from my react native app (android). But I can't completely understand how to build correct URL to pass in `Linking.openURL` function.

I've decompiled Get Taxi Drivers apk, in AndroidManifest.xml I can see this

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/login_activity_lable" android:name="com.gettaxi.dbx.android.activities.LoginActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize">
  <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But I can't understand how to use it to launch this application